# Proper way to create a co-sqlite3 db object outside of a middleware

Tags: node.js, sqlite, koa, co

I am trying to implement a db access layer within my koa application. This works fine:

```
var sqlite3 = require('co-sqlite3');
var services = require('./services/services');

app.use(function *(next){
    this.db = yield sqlite3(services.file);
    yield next
});
```

but I don't want to expose the database to every middleware in the app. In order to prevent this, I tried running `.setup()` outside of the middleware: `services.setup();` which is defined as:

```
var models = require('../models/models');
var path = require('path');
var sqlite3 = require('co-sqlite3');


module.exports = {
    file: path.join(__dirname, '../data/db.db'),
    setup: function () {
        var database = yield sqlite3(this.file);
        console.log('Database connected...');
        database.run("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        database.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BLOG_POST_BODIES; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BLOG_POSTS;");
        database.run(models.blog_posts);
        database.run(models.users);
        console.log('database created...');

        database.run("INSERT INTO BLOG_POST_BODIES(BODY) VALUES('HELLO WORLD');");
        var x = database.run("SELECT * FROM BLOG_POST_BODIES");
        console.log(x);
    }
};
```

the `models` objects just has scripts to run to create the blog posts and user tables.

The line giving me trouble is `var database = yield sqlite3(this.file);`
It gives me the following error:

```
var database = yield sqlite3(this.file);
                     ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Which I guess is right because there's nothing to `yield` forward to. But when I make `setup()` a generator function it does not execute. Likewise, when I remove the `yield` statement it tells me that `database.run is not a function`.

I'm stuck on this, can't figure out how to implement it properly.

#### Edit:

If I make `.setup()` a generator function and have all the `database` calls `yield` then it creates the tables and executes everything as expected...

```
app.use(function *(next){
    this.db = yield services.setup();
    yield next
});
```

But I don't want to expose the db to all the other middlewares, so I'm back to the same original problem.

*How can I set up the `co-sqlite3` database without including it in my middlewares?*

Comment: `yield` only works inside generator functions. The keyword is not allowed in ordinary functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `service.setup()` is a generator function.

A cleaner solution would be be:

```
app.use(function *() {
  if (!this.db) {                   // this is application context in KoaJS
    this.db = yield service.setup();
  }
  yield next;
});

app.use(function *businessLogic() {});
```

Other possible way will be:

```
app.use(function *() { });
app.use(function *() { });
co(services.setup).then(function(val) {
  var service = val;
  app.listen(3000);     // use the service variable inside
});
```

Comment: that will run it once (I feel dumb for not thinking of it!) But I don't want the database to be exposed like that... My database is a separate app mounted with `koa-mount`. Will the database be available in other app contexts?

Comment: Actually if I add it as necessary to middleware called in my router that should work, right? I'll need to test it when I get home...

Comment: The app context is shared among the requests. So every request can have access to the database.